# python float precision issue

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point

I encountered a strange float number problem of python(2.7.3).

```
In [4]: 17 * 0.1
Out[4]: 1.7000000000000002
```

but

```
In [5]: print(17*0.1)
1.7
```

Two questions:

1. why `17*0.1` is `1.7000000000000002` ?
2. why `print` is fine?

Comment: 1. IEEE-754 floating point rules. 2. IEEE-754 floating point rules. 3. Consider [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: The `print` is *not* fine. It simply displays the numbers with less digits in order to provide a nicer and more intuitive representation. You generally do not care if the number has an error in the order of 10^-16 or so. If you want to control the number of digits to display than use a format string: `print('{.Nf}'.format(17*0.1))`. Change `N` to change the number of digits to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good explanation here:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html